# Bulma card content change color

Tags: css, bulma

I run into a little problem. 
I want to change the background of a card content. But nothing worked.
I have this code part:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 75%!important;">
....
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="content">
....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.card .content {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)!important;
}
```

Comment: Please add your all related code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using sass with your bulma project you can change variables `$card-color` and `$card-background-color`. https://bulma.io/documentation/components/card/

or

You can add a new style to the `card` class and set the `background-color` property.

```
.card {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the pre-defined background colour classes such as `has-background-light`

https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/color-helpers/#background-color

```
<div class="card has-background-light" style="width: 75%!important;">
....
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="content">
....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```